# Regex to check range in ascii's order using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to make a condition that check some alphabet in range that have ASCII's order in Perl and surrounded by bracket. Like finding `[abc]` or `[a-c]`. I have used `/\[[a-z]\]/` or `/\[([a-z]),([a-z])\]/` but this just finds one character inside the bracket ex: `[d]`.

Comment: This is not clear. Please specify your input and expected output.

Comment: *but this just finds one character inside the bracket ex: [d]* -- That's because brackets only match 1 character.  However, any regex can be made to match more than one character by adding a modifier after the regex: `*` => 0 or more, `+` => one or more,  `{3}` => 3 times, `{3,}` => three or more,  `{3, 6}` => between 3 and 6 times.  See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will do as you ask

```
/\[(?:[a-z](?:-[a-z])?)+\]/
```